# how to freeze go button in soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-softkeyboard

I have a webView in my project, When I click go buttton in soft keyboard, the form submits and an error is returned. I want to hide the keyboard instead of form submission. plz help.

Answer (score 0):

I read about this a little and i think you might be looking for android:imeOptions="actionDone" (or maybe actionNone).
Didn't try it myself yet... see more info here: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html
under "Controlling the action buttons"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to only give answers when you know for sure that they work. Otherwise, please make it a comment.